# Eclipse c++11 thread support not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, c++11

I have followed the recommendations of other answers on SO, but still Eclipse will not build my threaded application:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void func() {
  std::cout << "Hello thread!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::thread t(func);
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the commands Eclipse is using (emphasis mine):

> g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 **-pthread -std=c++11** -MMD
>   -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
>
> g++ **-pthread -std=c++11** -o "sandbox"  ./main.o

As you can see, I added -pthread and -std=c++11.  Still, Eclipse complains at run-time:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not
>   permitted

Also, building manually fails:

```
 $ g++ main.cpp -o main.out -pthread -std=c++11

 $ ./main.out 
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
   what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to add the following to two locations:

```
-Wl,--no-as-needed
```

It should be added to:

1) Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Other flags

Example: `-c -fmessage-length=0 -pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed`

2) Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Miscellaneous -> Linker flags

Example: `-pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed`

Comment: I am not sure `-Wl,--no-as-needed` is a good idea, see [What is `--as-needed`?](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Quality_Assurance/As-needed) I cannot reproduce the error you describe on my machine.